# How to avoid problems when filming in a bath house

Tags: filming

I'm going to cover a concert early June inside a bath house. I've visited the location and it's both quite hot and humid. The plan is to bring in at least three video cameras and have them running constantly for an hour or so (there will be a Panasonic GH2, a Canon  HF10, and probably some fairly cheap sony video camera). I will also use a couple of self-powered michrophones (such as the zoom H1).

External power is of course something I will have to abandon, but are there any other tips what I should think of to keep this event safe and high-quality? What kind of problems can I expect to run into?

Comment: Don't slip on the soap. Ok, seriously, have a buddy keep an eye on the gear that you are not using so you still have it when you leave.

Answer (score 2):

Get underwater housings for your cameras. Since it doesn't sound like you will actually be dunking the gear under the water, you can probably get away with the cheap bag-type housings.

To avoid fogging up the lenses, let your gear warm up to the ambient temperature, then clean the lens.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to clearify this last point?

Comment: Sure - if your gear is cooler than the ambient temperature, water from the steam in the air will condense onto it. This is very obvious if you wear glasses in the winter. As soon as you step inside, your glasses will fog up until they warm up. The same is true of camera lenses. So give your gear some time to warm up and you should have an easier time with the lenses fogging up.